# Part of data gets removed after several writings and readings of SQLite3 database table

Tags: python, database, sqlite

In my Python application (Qt application using Pyside6) I am using SQLite3 databases for data storage.
I save my DataFrames in the database tables, query data from these tables to do calculations with them and show the results in my application.

After multiple rounds of saving and reading data (see code snippets of how I save the data below) working as expected with always using the same functions, parts of my data suddenly get deleted from the database table without having any delete query in my code for this specific table.

**These are my code snippets for data saving:**
The code below is a short version of my try, except, finally code block just showing the sql relevant code.

```
#Getting connection:
con = sqlite3.connect(f'./xxxx/{name}.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
table_name = "xyz"

#Check if table already exists in the database
check_table_query = f"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='{table_name}';"

#table exists
if table_exists:
  #Get already existing data from the table
  cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM '{table_name}'")
  existing_data = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
  
  #no data in table, new data will all be saved in the table
  if existing_data.empty:
     print("existing data from db is empty")
     table_to_save.to_sql(table_name, con, if_exists='append', index=False)
     # Commit the transaction
     con.commit()

  #new data will be compared to existing data and just new rows will be saved in table
  else:
     existing_data.columns = table_to_save.columns
     table_to_save = table_to_save[~table_to_save.isin(existing_data.to_dict('list')).all(1)]

     #Append the new data to the table
     if not table_to_save.empty:
        table_to_save.to_sql(table_name, con, if_exists='append', index=False)
        # Commit the transaction
        con.commit()
     else:
        print("Data already in db, no saving needed.")


#table does not exist, table will be created and new data will be saved in this table
else:
   table_to_save.to_sql(table_name, con, if_exists='append', index=False)
   #Commit the transaction
   con.commit()

#Close the connection
con.close()
```

To query the data, I use simple "SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE x = y ORDER BY z" queries. The reading queries work as expected and give me always the data being saved in the database table.

The amount of rows in the database table can reach approx. 20 million. Is it possible that with increasing amount of rows inside the database table this unexpected deletion of data can happen? It is so strange that my code works several times and always after few rounds of saving and reading data, the deletion happens. I would be very glad, if someone knows this phenomenon and has a possible solution!

Comment: Please provide a reproductible example and, if possible, some logs that shows the problem you describe. Answering as is is almost impossible.

Comment: How exactly do you know that something is missing? What is missing (one or a few rows, many rows, data in rows but the rows themselves are still there)?

Comment: I observed the table in the DB Browser and many rows are completely missing (not only the data in the rows, the complete rows are gone) which were there before.

Comment: The path to the database is relative. Are you sure that there weren't two or more similar database files created accidentally?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Michael Butscher! I checked that , it is just one database file